# I live in the Netherlands. How can my 14-year-old daughter and her grandfather visit me from India?

Tags: indian-citizens, schengen-visas, netherlands, minors, visa-sponsors

I live in the Netherlands with a Residence Permit as a highly-skilled migrant. My daughter lives with her father and grandparents in India. She is a minor and 14 years old.

Can I apply for a sponsored visa for my daughter to travel from India to visit the Netherlands with her grandfather? My daughter and my father will travel together from India to the Netherlands.

What is the process of issuing a consent letter? How the consent letter can be notarized in the Netherlands?

Comment: Is this for a short-term or long-term visit?

Comment: This will be a short team visitor visa for my daughter to come from India to Netherland.

Comment: @sudeshnaBanerjee Hi Sudeshna, you should edit your question with the information that you want her to have a short-term visitor visa. However, I realized that you use 'sponsor' and 'consent'. A sponsor letter would be about how you would pay their costs, and you would need to provide your financial details for their visa applications. A consent letter would give permission for your daughter to travel with her grandfather. Her father may also need to provide one. Are you interested in both types of letters?

Comment: Belongs on this site. The question is about making a short term visit.

Comment: @DJClayworth I have retracted my close vote and deleted my comment.

Comment: The list of required documents is [here](https://www.vfsglobal.com/netherlands/india/pdf/checklist-visa-application-tourism.pdf) including a link to a *Proof of Sponsorship form*